# Formatting XML as HTML Table

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm trying to format a very simple xml file into a very simple HTML table.

I have to use an external CSS stylesheet with the XSLT.  The problem I'm encountering is that it's not separating the elements into specific rows- such as all the day elements in one row, etc.  It's putting them all into one line.  Other examples that I've seen sort them all into individual rows, so I bet I just did something ridiculous.

Thanks for looking!

xml: This is only part.  There are 5 records.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="forecast.xsl"?>
<forecast week="June 1st 2016"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="forecast.xsd">
    <day>
        <Weekday>Monday</Weekday>
        <HiTemp>84</HiTemp> 
        <LoTemp>74</LoTemp> 
        <Wind>SSE 18 mph</Wind> 
        <Humidity>59%</Humidity> 
        <DewPoint>68 degrees</DewPoint> 
        <Visibility>10 miles</Visibility> 
        <UVIndex>4 of 10</UVIndex> 
        <Sunrise>6:01 AM</Sunrise>
        <Sunset>8:49 PM</Sunset>
    </day>
    <day>
        <Weekday>Tuesday</Weekday>
        <HiTemp>89</HiTemp> 
        <LoTemp>77</LoTemp> 
        <Wind>NW 6 mph</Wind> 
        <Humidity>68%</Humidity> 
        <DewPoint>54 degrees</DewPoint> 
        <Visibility>8 miles</Visibility> 
        <UVIndex>6 of 10</UVIndex> 
        <Sunrise>6:03 AM</Sunrise>
        <Sunset>8:51 PM</Sunset>
      </day>
    </forecast>
```

and my xslt:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Weekly Forecast</title>
            <link href="forecast.css"
                rel="stylesheet" />
        </head>
        <body>
            <h3>weekly Forecast</h3>
            <table border="1">
                <tr>
                    <th>Weekday</th>
                    <th>High Temp</th>
                    <th>Low Temp</th>
                    <th>Wind</th>
                    <th>Humidity</th>
                    <th>DewPoint</th>
                    <th>Visibility</th>
                    <th>UVIndex</th>
                    <th>Sunrise</th>
                    <th>Sunset</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <xsl:for-each select="forecast/day">

                    <td><xsl:value-of select="Weekday"/></td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="HiTemp"/></td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="LoTemp"/></td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="Wind"/></td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="Humidity"/></td>
                    <td> <xsl:value-of select="DewPoint"/></td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="Visibility"/></td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="UVIndex"/></td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="Sunrise"/></td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="Sunset"/></td>

                </xsl:for-each>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And the css is pretty basic:

```
body{background-color:teal;
    margin:0 auto;
    }
table {border: 3px solid black;}
th {font-weight:bold;
    color:white;
    font-size:14px;
    display:block;}
tr {color:white;
    font-size:14px;
    display:block;}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the `<tr>` and `</tr>` tags that are around the `<xsl:for-each>` belong *inside* the `<xsl:for-each>`